# How to check an item in an CheckedListBox from code behind

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox that contains 3 values which are added manually and not from code behind.

This is how the CheckedListBox looks like:

[image]

I would like to add that these values are always the same in the same order, they never change.

This is my question:

- Is possible to access these values from code behind so I can check them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CheckedListBox` in winforms has various properties - `Items`, `CheckedItems`, `CheckedIndices` for maniuplating it from the C# side.

You can check them by calling `SetItemChecked`.